# Need help diagnosing pepper pests

Tags: identification, diagnosis, pests, peppers, outdoor

I am trying to figure out what is eating holes in the leaves of my plants ( habinero and sweet pepper ).  Primarily the holes are in the centre of leaves, with some on the edge of one leaf.  and the most affected plants have a stringy white substance similar to spiderwebs on top side of the leaves, and what looks like grains of salt.  I have not seen any insects on the leaves with the exception of a fly that landed there while taking pictures. Images at the link below.

I have sprayed down the soil with a mix of cayenne pepper, oil, soap, and water a few days ago to prevent squirrels from digging up the plants.

Each plant is potted along with a few daffodil bulbs to aid further with squirrels.

I am growing in southern ontario, canada.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjMq0.jpg

Comment: The large holes look like they were made by slugs, but AFAIK, slugs tend to not feed on peppers/tomatoes/potatoes. Two of the close-ups appear to show aphids or, maybe, thrips, but the damage they would cause is not related to the large holes or chunks missing from leaves.

Comment: I did pick up some "Ortho Bug B Gon" and sprayed it down yesterday, today it seems like nothing has really gotten any worse.  I also have not seen any more bugs and i have yet to see any slugs or snails.  I will keep an eye on them and hopefully that spray works and is all that is needed.